# Html comment sign in html output

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea, output

I have a simple html document, in which I have a form with a textarea..
when I submit the form, it will be saved through a php site to the database, and the site will be refreshed, and will output the content of the database.. BUT, if i want to use a arrow like this <-- (with the lines together) in the textarea, then everything I write after the arrow is not displayed on the website, and is not saved in the database..

i tried to google the problem, but couldnt find an answer

can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: `urlencode()` the data before processing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use htmlentities() function:

Try below code

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" >
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['text']))
echo $id = htmlentities($_GET['text']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this,

try searching google for

```
urlencode()

htmlspecialchars()

htmlentities()
```

to find the specific one that suits your needs.

You would call that function on your data before inserting into the database.

Answer (score 1):

-- means comment on SQL. You must escape from --

Answer (score 0):

Please use prepared statements to prevent any of these types of issues http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php